# How to properly operate with wstrings?

Tags: c++, visual-c++, c++17, wstring

I am learning about wstrings because I want to understand UTF-8 for a project. I made a simple program to test operations using wstrings:

```
int main()
{
   std::wstring test;
   std::wstring test2;
   std::wstring test3;
   int n;

   getline(std::wcin, test);

   std::wcout << "\n" << test;

   for (n = 0; n < test.size(); n++)
   {
      test[n] += n * n;
      test2[n] = test[n];
   }
   std::wcout << test2 << "\n";

   for (n = 0; n < test2.size(); n++)
   {
    test2[n] -= n * n;
    test3[n] = test[n];
   }
   std::wcout << test3 << "\n";

  return 0;
}
```

When I execute it I get this error : "string subscript out of range"

It's my first C++ "serious" project and any help is appreciated!

Comment: note that `std::wstrings` and `utf-8` are unlikely to be related, on windows for example `std::wstring` is `utf-16` encoded

Comment: Really? I am actually kinda lost on that. I thought I needed wstrings because, for some reason, when I used std::string the characters in test2 and test3 would not pass the 0 - 255 part of the Unicode characters. Thank you for the information.

Comment: yep you should use `std::u8string` in c++20 or just `std::string` before to store utf-8 https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string

Comment: @GuilhermeGaldino `std::wstring` uses `wchar_t` elements, which are 2 bytes in size on Windows and 4 bytes on other platforms. So a `std::wstring` is UTF-16 encoded on Windows, and UTF-32 encoded on other platforms.  `std::string` uses `char` elements, which are 1 byte in size on all platforms. Prior to C++20, a `std::string` can hold a UTF-8 encoded string. C++20 adds `char8_t` and `std::u8string` for that purpose instead. Any UTF encoded string can handle the whole of Unicode. But most Windows API functions prefer local ANSI or UTF-16 strings only.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your `test2` string is empty, so when you do:

```
test2[n] = test[n];
```

you are indexing at an invalid location, which invokes undefined behavior. This could result in an exception being thrown.

Instead, you can do:

```
test2.push_back(test[n]);
```

You have the same issue with `test3`, which you can fix the same way.

---

Alternatively, once you read in `test`, you can initialize `test2` and `test3` with the appropriate number of elements:

```
getline(std::wcin, test);

std::wstring test2(test.size());
std::wstring test3(test.size());
```

and now you can index into these strings without any problems.

---

Also, for your problem, you don't even need to do any indexing into `test2`. Once you've modified `test`, you can simply assign it like this:

```
for (n = 0; n < test.size(); n++)
{
      test[n] += n * n;
}
std::wstring test2 = test;
```

and similarly for `test3`.